# Quotes and spaces in an argument to asyncio.create_subprocess_exec() in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-asyncio, python-3.9

I need to call a subprocess from an asyncio Python program running on Windows as such:

`process.exe -SomeNormalArg -SomeArgField="Some Value with Spaces"`

I'm currently running it like so:

config.json:

```
{
  "args": [
    "-SomeNormalArg",
    "-SomeArgField=\"Some Value with Spaces\""
  ] 
}
```

program.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import json
args = loads(open('config.json').read())['args']


async def main():
    await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('process.exe', *args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

...But the process is spawning as `process.exe -SomeNormalArg "-SomeArgField=\"Some Value with Spaces\""`.

I've read the [Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence) bit from the Python docs, but I can't come up with a way to make this work.

I should mention that `create_subprocess_shell()` with a full string of the command functions as a workaround, but it's a messy solution.

Comment: Hi @user4815162342, it worked! Sorry for the delay, got pulled into another project. Thank you for the assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overquoting. The quotes in `-SomeArgField="Some Value with Spaces"` are only needed to prevent the shell from splitting the argument by whitespace, passing its content as separate arguments to the subprocess. Since you're using `create_subrocess_exec` which doesn't go through a shell, you don't have that problem to begin with and don't need to quote at all:

```
{
  "args": [
    "-SomeNormalArg",
    "-SomeArgField=Some Value with Spaces"
  ] 
}
```

That appears counter-intuitive if you're used to starting the program from a shell, but otherwise it exactly matches what you actually want to pass to the subprocess. (The subprocess won't parse quotes, the shell or the C runtime does that.)